# Substring of each line of some data in a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm working with an Android log file, In the logs we are pushing some data that may be used as a training set.

This is roughly how the relevant logs look

```
[Timestamp] : [Function name] : 1.1 1.2 1.3...
[Timestamp] : [Function name] : 2.1 2.2 2.3...
```

I want to trim this data to just the floating point numbers at the end, so that we can convert it to csv.

This is what I tried

```
Get-Content .\log.txt | Select-String "Function Name" | foreach {$_.substring(73)}
```

I'm getting an error that powershell doesn't have a method named substring

Comment: 73 is arbitrary number where the function name ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If really you'd like to follow this way - you can just enforce string

```
gc .\log.txt |Select-String "function name"  | % {([string]$_).substring(73) }
```

before adding [string]

Name                                     BaseType

---

MatchInfo                                System.Object

after adding [string]
Name                                     BaseType

---

String                                   System.Object

and of course you can sub**string** string :)

Comment: Ok,  so basically we type casted the output to  string.

Comment: You said "If really you'd like to follow this way", is there any other better way?